# What's the benefit to use ShutdowHook in java application

Tags: java

I'm exposed to `Shutdownhook` and learning about how to use it.
It's allowed to register `ShutdownHook` which will be called by JVM before JVM halts.
We can add some cleanup work in `ShutdownHook` like deleting temporary files and so on.
Ok, it does look like a method to shutdown current application gracefully.
However, I'm little confused about using it instead of just adding cleanup operations in WindowCloseListener in a **Swing application**.

Take samples below,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShutdownhookSample {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                frame.dispose();
                System.out.println("Close from listener...");
                /**
                 * Add cleanup operations here
                 */
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void start(){
                System.out.println("Close from shutdownhook...");
                /**
                 * Add cleanup operations here
                 */
            }
        });

    }
}
```

No matter I close the application by exit button or by "Close window" option in windows task bar, both of windows close listener and `ShutdownHook` are called. The only difference is that the ShutdownHook is called a little later than the windows close listener. And yes, no one is called if I force shutdown the process.

So here comes my question:

Is it really needed to use `ShutdownHook` in a **Swing application**? It seems that the windows close listener is enough to handle the cleanup operations. Is there any situation that can't be covered by windows close listener but ShutdownHook can?

Comment: NO, it is not needed in a Swing application... 20 years developing in Java, not only Swing, and I never needed it. *Used* it only for testing it.

Comment: A `ShutdownHook` will tell you when the JVM is terminated under normal circumstances. It's useful for terminating/releasing native resources which may not be managed by other parts of the application. *"Is it really needed to use ShutdownHook in a Swing application?"* - That depends on what your application is doing and how it's managing it's resources

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your comment, it does help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use feature X if that is what you need to do. Feature X existing isn't sufficient for it being used!

In other words: the shut down hook comes in handy when you are a creating a non UI application. Or when closing the main window isn't exiting your application. Think of an application that keeps running in the background and that can be resurrected via some tray bar icon.